# How to skip the update of state inside getDerivedStatefromProps() in childComponent only for the first time of rendering the childComponent

Tags: reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

> Hi I'm new to Reactjs.
>   I want {this.state.data} of the below childComponent to be incremented 5 on each time this component is getting loaded. 
>   So i'm doing that under the static method getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state)
>   But for the first time when it is loading {this.state.data} should be the initial value i have defined (Here it is 0).
>   So i'm expecting the below line output to be incremented 5 starting from 0(initial value i defined)
>
> Data from ClassChild : {data}

*Expected Output:*
Data from ClassChild : 0
Data from ClassChild : 5
Data from ClassChild : 10
Data from ClassChild : 15

*Actual Output:*
Data from ClassChild : 5
Data from ClassChild : 10
Data from ClassChild : 15
Data from ClassChild : 20

> Is there anyway to skip the first time execution of getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state), instead of defining the -5 value in  constructor to get the expected output?

````
class ClassChild extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.log("ClassChild constructor()")
        this.state = {
            data : 0
        }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state){
        console.log("ClassChild getDerivedStateFromProps()")
        return {
            data : state.data + props.childIncState
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {count, childIncState} = this.props
        const {data} = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <div>Count from ClassParent : {count}</div>
                <div>Value to be incremented in ClassChild : {childIncState}</div>
                <div>Data from ClassChild : {data}</div>
                {console.log("ClassChild render()")}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ClassChild;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). It is not called for the initial render.

Here is an example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(prevProps.childIncState !== this.props.childIncState) {
      setState({data: this.state.data + props.childIncState});
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Snaksa, Thanks for ur answer. It really helped me  if I change the condition as if(preState.data === this.state.data) instead of if(prevProps.childIncState !== this.props.childIncState). Since childIncState is a constant sending from parent component, if condition becomes false always.